# sensitive data exposure from RAM memory

Tags: memory, sensitive-data-exposure

I have software written in C# and compiled as a .exe file.

How can I read sensitive data (like usernames, passwords, etc.) from RAM while it runs?

Comment: Depends on the OS, permissions, isolation, etc. Your question lacks a ton of details. In e.g. MS-DOS, Windows 1.0-ME all applications have full access to RAM.

Comment: we can consider that end users use windows 10. my question is about a attack that eavesdrop RAM data.

Comment: You want to search using the term "read RAM for sensitive data". That will give you all the duplicate questions I linked and many, many more.